# Getting Value Of Email Type Field In DNN XSLT

Tags: xslt, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to set up a contact form using the DNN Form and List Module and one of the fields I have set for Enquirers as a dropdown with an Email Type selected and have got the form submitting to the different emails depending on which enquiry is selected in the dropdown. To achieve this I have entered the List of Values as "Captain|x@gmail.com ..;" in Email Settings.

What my issue is regarding is when I receive the email with the form results, this particular field in the results shows the Email and not the Caption. I am trying to change the text in XSLT but it always hit otherwise. If I change the type of field to text then the following works. Can I not make a comparison with an email type?

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="udt:I_x0020_am_x0020_a='x@gmail.com'">display some note in email</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="udt:I_x0020_am_x0020_a='y@gmail.com'">display some note in email 2</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>It will always hit here</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
```

this gives me the value of the dropdown list

```
 <xsl:value-of select="udt:I_x0020_am_x0020_a" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Using caption works.

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="udt:I_x0020_am_x0020_a_UDT_Caption='x@gmail.com'">1</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>2</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
```